# Ruby On Rails, Reputation System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i've plan for my Rails Apps where user could have reputation like good/bad user. In your opinion how do I best implement a reputation system to for my user ?. Currently I am interested to apply such a reputation system on Ebay, between buyer and seller. Is there any tutorial and gem/plugin to implement web reputation system especially in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twitter released an open sourced gem related to this recently:

https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what u looking for: https://github.com/vshvedov/vote_fu_rails_3